# Long/multiple SQL queries vs Serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, performance, serialization

I'm trying to improve the performance of my web app where a page does a long query to pull data from different tables on a database. It pulls invoice data with multiple item lines, invoice status, and with each line having additional properties from another table.

Is serialization worth considering for improvement? The tables are related and in normalized form.

Comment: this one is using entity framework and pulling out several related entities in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d first do some profiling on the queries just to make sure that they are running as efficiently as they can – simply adding an index in the correct place may solve the problem.

If the queries are fine then I would look at data caching in ASP.NET. The following link is a good article on this: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111559/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100902-1.aspx

Comment: wondering how other sites stretch the use of caching, i have a couple thousand records to cache if ever.

Comment: The amount you can put in the cache depends on the memory on the web server. However, if you only have a few thousand records to put in the cache I can’t see you having any problems.